# 3 tables many to many how to create relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have tables name category, post and user.
Users can follow categories

> users are relationship many to many with categories 
>   posts are relationship many to many with categories 
>   users are relationship one to many posts
>   Now I want to get all posts from categories in which categories has follow user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you right:

- You have an entity User. This user is categorized by several
  categories. And a category has several Users too.
- Also your entity Post is categorized by several categories and vice
  versa.
- And a user    can make several posts and a post can belong to several
  users

So if that's what you want to have, you just need to model each relationship as a table:

```
USER(KEY, NAME, ...)
CATEGORY(KEY, DESC, ...)
POST(KEY, CONTENT, ...)

USER_2_CATEGORY(USER_KEY, CATEGORY_KEY)
POST_2_CATEGORY(POST_KEY, CATEGORY_KEY)
USER_2_POST(USER_KEY, POST_KEY)
```